# How to check for duplicate file contents

Tags: python, django

I am checking whether a file uploaded already has duplicates of that file.
I am using cosine similarity to do the content check.

That works fine, but I thinking this way of running a task with for loops of documents that are already accepted against uploaded files that haven't been accepted(processing) yet is not practical.

So what would be a more better way to go out this?

```
    documents_processing = Document.objects.filter(status='processing')
    documents = Document.objects.filter(status='accepted')
    for processing in documents_processing:
        for document in documents:
            # If cosine similary > .9:
            # Stop and update processing document as status=denied, comment=duplicate

            cosine_similarity = get_cosine_similary(document, processing)
       
            if cosine_similarity > 0.9:
                processing.status = 'denied'
                processing.comment = 'duplicate'
                processing.save()
            else:
                processing.status = 'accepted'
                processing.save()
```

What would be the suggestions here for a more efficient code?

Comment: There are solutions for fast nearest neighbors lookup, like ScaM and Faiss. They will bring down the lookup complexity to ~O(log n) from O(n^2)

Comment: if you care about exact duplication and not "similarity" (that's what duplication implies) then you can directly compare the memory byte-to-byte using an optimized library, otherwise just hash() if you don't care about speed that much.

Comment: I would personally store hashes of memory every time a file is uploaded so you only ever hash a file once. and you can do instant set lookups on existing hashes

Comment: @OctaviodelSer thank you. I ended up using hash() and all seems well.